# Upgraded to Windows 11 now L2TP VPN Connection Fails

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, l2tp

I upgraded to Windows 11 now my VPN connections fail.  They were working right before the update.  The error is...

*The L2TP connection attempt failed because the security layer encountered a processing error during initial negotiations with the remote computer*.

1. I've tried everything mentioned in [this article](https://windowsreport.com/vpn-error-789)
2. and in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTjiwpwTr0A)
3. Uninstalling kb:5009543 [mentioned here](https://borncity.com/win/2022/01/12/windows-vpn-verbindungen-l2tp-over-ipsec-nach-januar-2022-update-kaputt/) didn't work either.
4. After I did all the items in [this article](https://windowsreport.com/cannot-connect-l2tp-vpn-windows-10/) I did get a slightly different result, it now says  "Connecting to [IP]" and spins for a minute or two then shows the same error.  Before I would get the error immediately.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't pretend to speak for everyone but I'm not following links and/or sitting through videos to guess at what you did, please document clearly what you tried, what you expected and what happened. Also, what do the server logs say

Comment: @Ginnungagap I usually do that. Just trying to be efficient. I can list it all out when I get back to be a PC but it will make this post about 10 pages long.

Answer (score 0):

You updated to Windows 11 on the wrong day. There is a current bug in Windows 11 that has broken L2TP VPNs.  It's not just you: it's being pushed out in Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after [this article was published yesterday](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/new-windows-kb5009543-kb5009566-updates-break-l2tp-vpn-connections/). It wasn't directly related to Windows 11.  I just happened to upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11 the same morning that security vulnerabilities and bugs update **KB5009566** dropped.  That is what is breaking L2TP VPN connections.  If you uninstall it, which I don't recommend, they will work again.

Run -> cmd ->

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:5009566
```